# Getting the last object's element present in an array

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a `Person`(`NSObject`) Class with following properties: `Number`, `Pin`, `Name`.

Lets say I have "N" number of person present in an array. How can I find out the last person's `Number`, `pin`, `Name`.

I have find out following method but I am not getting anything from this

```
id object=[myPersonArray lastObject];
```

Comment: how is the myPersonArray init and alloc'ed? Are you sure it is not empty.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
Person *lastPerson = [myPersonArray lastObject];
```

Now you can access the properties and methods of `lastPerson`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply find total size of array and then `count-1` give the value of last object.

```
int countArray = [myPersonArray count];

NSString *stringLastIndex = [myPersonArray objectAtIndex:countArray-1];
```

and `another solution` is you can use `[myPersonArray lastObject]`.

Comment: which solution you are using 1st or 2nd?

Comment: NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Kuwait",@"Japan ", @"USA",  nil];
    
NSLog(@"%@" , [array objectAtIndex:[array count]-1]);

Comment: I'm referring to the line where you call `objectAtIndex:`. Your are missing something critical.

Comment: ..which is the zero indexed array. Accessing the "count"s object will result in a range out of bounds exception, since the last object is at index count-1. @rmaddy Just say it :) lastObject is the much better choice.

Comment: @Mario I think people tend to learn better if they have to think about it. Simply telling them is easier but not always better. Proof reading is an important skill. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you should do:

```
Person *person = [myPersonArray lastObject];
NSLog("Name: %@", person.name);
```